# How to get file from the root folder?

Tags: c#

I had One folder. That folder contains so many sub folders. That each sub folders has so many folders and folder **MNC**. that MNC folder contains so many files and also **.txt** files. How to get that **.txt** files when I give the path of that main root folder. i.e For Example, I have a root folder name **A**. **A** folder contains so many sub folders. That each sub folders have so many folders and folder **MNC** and **MNC** folder had so many files and also **.txt** files. If I give the path of folder **A** then It should give the **.txt** files as output. I tried some types. But I can't get the correct output. Please help me for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so its like `yourfolder\???\MNC\???.txt`? you want to get all text files?

Comment: Please show what you have tried, it helps to clarify your problem. from what I can tell you are looking to GetFiles from `root\MNC`

Comment: Have a look at `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` and `Directory.EnumerateFiles`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I worked on that .txt files for retrieving some content by directly using that .txt file path. I have code for only retrieving information from that text files. I tried some Directory.getdirectories and directory.getfiles like types for getting .txt file from root folder. But I can't get output from that. I didn't have much more knowledge on this directory retrieving. that's why I posted here. @Martin Mulder,Sayse,il_raffa

Comment: I've seen code by using Directory.EnumerateDirectories and Directory.EnumerateFiles. But It gives all .txt files in all sub folders in 'A'. I need .txt file only in MNC folder. @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes I need like that. @M.kazemAkhgary Akhgary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all txt files by executing:

```
        //Gets all *.txt files
        string rootDir = @"C:\\Dokumentai\\Files\\A";
        var txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(rootDir, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        Console.WriteLine("txtFiles count:" + txtFiles.Count());

        //Filter only txt files from "root\[any folder]\MNC\*.txt", 
        //the pattern can be improoved, becouse it takes all TXT files from from MNC folder including it subfolders...
        string patternt = rootDir+@"\\(.*)\\MNC\\(.*).txt";
        //From each file before compare raplacing "\\" to "\"
        var txtFilesOnlyFromMncFolders = txtFiles.Where(filePath => Regex.IsMatch( filePath.Replace(@"\\", @"\"), patternt, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).ToList();            
        Console.WriteLine("txtFiles count:" + txtFilesOnlyFromMncFolders.Count());
        // Printing founded files for debug purpose
        foreach (var file in txtFilesOnlyFromMncFolders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
```

Then you can get content of file by

```
foreach(file in txtFiles)
{
    //Check if file exists
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        //Do something with file content
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want the .txt files in only subfolder 'MNC'. Your code gives .txt files in all sub folders in 'A'. @Drasius

Comment: Look at updated post. Next time try to write clearer. The question is queti complicated to understand.